# Next.js api routes image upload issue coming from client

Tags: javascript, file-upload, next.js, fetch-api

I've been stuck on this bug for the past couple hours and I cannont seem to find the reason. Essentially, I'm trying to write a api route in next.js that will able to modify the image and then upload it to storage. Whenever I upload an image from localhost and the call the fetch request, the there is no file found in the api route and I get returned an empty object. However, when I make the request from postman, everything works. I have no idea what would be different between the two and I would appreciate any help!

This is the code on the client that gets called. {} is logged to the console

```
 onClick={async () => {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("image", imageFile);
      const res = await fetch("/api/cropImages", {
        method: "POST",
        data,
      });
      console.log(await res.json());
    }}
```

Here is my api route

```js
import { IncomingForm } from "formidable";
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
export default async (req, res) => {
  const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const form = new IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve({ fields, files });
    });
  });
  const file = data?.files?.image;
  console.log(file);
  res.status(200).json({ file });
};
```

This is the request on Postman

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2qYn.png)

Here is the image file:
[imagefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpVu7.png)

Comment: Its a image file from an input tag. Ill edit my question to show it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your problem can have been that you had this onCLick function on your submit button (for form element) applied and you didn't preventDefault() on you method and instead of using logic in your onClick method it was trying to send form diferently.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please write a comment instead.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."